# convert array to nested json (without reference)

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

This JSON represents an Employee -> Supervisor relationship that looks like this:

```
{
    "Pete": "Nick",
    "Barbara": "Nick",
    "Nick": "Sophie",
    "Sophie": "Jonas"
}
```

In this case, Nick is a supervisor of Pete and Barbara, Sophie supervises Nick.

i want to make it hierarchy as this

```
{“Jonas" : [
   {“Sophie":  [
       {“Nick" : [
            {"Pete": []},
            {"Barbara": []}
       ]}
   ]}
]}
```

I tried to make an array for the keys and values ( even index for value and odd for keys )

```
$i =0;
$arr[] = array();
            foreach ($files as $key => $f)
            {

                    $arr[$i] = $f;
                    $i++;
                    $arr[$i] = $key;
                    $i++;
            }
```

the iterate to find the root that have even index and not duplicate

```
$i++;
                    for($x=0;$x<=6;$x+2){
                        for($z=1;$z<7;$z+2){
                            if($arr[$x] != $arr[$z]){
                               #som code   
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

then find the children which  is the next of it, but works only with the root

can some one help

Comment: Can you show us some code? Did you tried something?

Comment: Hello Hayder, welcome to StackOverflow! This question seems like an homework assignment. Please note, that SO is not a service doing work for you, but if you show what you already tried and where you struggle you will receive help from the community. You might get downvotes for "no attempt" until you fix this, here are some hints: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: @DBX12 
 i tried  a lot of think its work only when i have reference key Like 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15394681/get-nested-hierarchical-json-from-array-php

Comment: It is possible to iterate over an array while getting keys and values of the array. Please add what you tried.

Comment: btw, no need to take an array for more than one supervidsed person.

Comment: So you are coding in PHP and not JS?

Comment: @DBX12 i added some code i don't know if it would help you

Comment: @Eddie
it's ok if i solve it with js
i tagged js because i found many libraries do something like this but i clould not use it and hope some one to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume input data are valid (no circular references) and only one person is head (in [first version](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/55724297/1) of question you not mention that your code in PHP
(and you also use javascript tag) so I provide answer in JS, however you can still use it on frontend side)

```js
let s={
    "Pete": "Nick",
    "Barbara": "Nick",
    "Nick": "Sophie",
    "Sophie": "Jonas"
}

let t={};                                        // t is temporary object
let head=Object.values(s).find(x=>!(x in s))     // find head
Object.entries(s).flat().map(x=>t[x]={[x]:[]})   // t contains name-objects
Object.keys(s).map(x=> t[s[x]][s[x]].push(t[x])) // object nesting in t

console.log(t[head]);
```

Object.entries... line will produce following content in t={"Pete":{"Pete":[]},"Nick":{"Nick":[]},"Barbara":{"Barbara":[]},"Sophie":{"Sophie":[]},"Jonas":{"Jonas":[]}} - so it prepare objects for each name (in s keys and values). The Object.keys... line read Employee x in s, find its Supervisor s[x], finds Supervisor name-object t[s[x]] and get array of this object t[s[x]][s[x]] and push to it reference to Employee named-object t[x]. At beginign we find head and 'head-object' t[head] which contains whole structure. This is the idea.

Comment: can we do the same with php ?